# Camera speed in A-frame

Tags: aframe

I'm creating a scene in A-frame, but the camera wasd movement is too fast, is there a way to slow down the movement? An older version (0.4.0) specified an acceleration property, but now it's gone.

I've tried the old code, but didn't worked.

```
<a-entity camera look-controls wasd-controls position="0 1.6 0" acceleration="5"></a-entity>
```

This doesn't work for the acceleration.

I'm using the version 0.9.0, and the acceleration code is for the 0.4.0.

Comment: You may want to specify the version of aframe you are using and add an example of the code you have tried. It will make it easier for others to understand

Comment: Thanks, I've edited it now.

Answer (score 1):

Acceleration must be a property of wasd-controls.

`<a-entity camera look-controls wasd-controls="acceleration: 5" position="0 1.6 0"></a-entity>`